# React - Updating the state with multiple form values

Tags: reactjs

I'm a bit of newbie to React and I'm creating an app for a wedding breakfast table plan with the MERN stack (MongoDB, Express, React, Node).

I've created a simple form component to add tables to the plan (and the app's DB). The form has two fields which collect:

- Table Name
- Table Capacity

I've been trying to POST these to the database on submit with Axios, but have read that its better practice with forms in React to have an onChange handler which updates the state as the user enters data, and an onSubmit handler which takes the data from the state and persists it to the DB. As shown below.

```js
class AddTableForm extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <section className="py-4">
        <div className="container">
          <h2>Add A Table</h2>
          <form action="/add-table" method="post" className="border p-3" onSubmit={this.props.addTableOnSubmit}>
            <label htmlFor="name" className="d-block">Table name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" onChange={this.props.addTableOnChange} required />
            <label htmlFor="capacity" className="d-block">Table capacity</label>
            <input type="number" name="capacity" id="capacity"  onChange={this.props.addTableOnChange} required />
            <input type="submit" value="Add Table" name="submit" className="d-block mt-3" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default AddTableForm;
```

My question is what is the best approach for updating the state with a form like this? The data from the form should update a state object called tabledata which takes the form of:

```js
this.state = {
  tabledata: [
    {
      name: 'Table One',
      capacity: 5,
    },
    {
      name: 'Table Two',
      capacity: 7,
    }
  ]
}
```

If I update the state on change I feel I will run into a lot of problems dealing with objects with incomplete data. Is it possible and/or better in this case for me to deal with everything on submit?

Comment: Have you already checked for this documentation from React Team: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: Yeah I've read that thanks. I think because I'm storing both of the form values in a single object within the state it becomes more complex than the examples they give in the docs. For instance, if the user completes the Capacity field on my form before a Name has been given, how will I know which object to update? Obviously the first time onChange is fired I will just create a new object, but on the second time I should surely update an existing object if there is one?

Answer (score 0):

The state object and onChange and OnSubmit methods shown above are part of a parent component in my project and passed down via props. I was trying to update a state object which holds data for all dinner tables when a user starts interacting with the Add Table Form.

I decided in the end, to break the state manipulation down into two stages:

- Have one state for the AddTableForm
- Another state in the parent component for all Tables

When a user interacts with the form, the onChange within the AddTableForm component is fired and builds up state for that particular form. When the user submits the form, the onSubmit handler calls a function in the parent component which then updates the state of all tables by adding this new table data into it.

This works great and I really hope this post helps someone else out someday.